# How best to handle an answer added to the question?

Tags: support, answering-questions

The poster of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/543385/are-there-via-integrated-sound-board-drivers-available-for-windows-8-that-fix-th) subsequently edited it and added a solution he had found. I left a comment asking him to post his edit as an answer instead (and self-accept if he feels like it), but he hasn't done so yet. Odd, because he's been a member of SO for over a year, and has self-answered before.

Anyway, suppose he never returns. In such cases it would be easy enough for any of us to move that solution to an answer, but is that the best way to go about it? In such situations can mods add answers as other users so the users get the credit? If not, should we add an answer and perhaps mark it as Community Wiki?

Comment: edit it out & post as an answer with all due attribution. You may/may not opt to tick it as CW

Comment: @Sathya: Done and done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions section is meant for questions, not answers. If a solution has been bolted onto the question, first step should be to drop a comment asking the person to move it to answers.

After a reasonable period of waiting period (48 hours so) - if the solution's still on the question, feel free to edit the solution question & move it to an answer, with an attribution to the author.

Marking it as CW is *optional*, you may or may not want to select it